# Split string on single forward slashes with RegExp

Tags: regex, vba, excel

edit: wow, thanks for so many suggestions, but I wanted to have a regexp solution specifically for future, more complex use.

I need support with splitting text string in VBA Excel. I looked around but solutions are either for other languages or I can't make it work in VBA.

I want to split words by single slashes only:

```
text1/text2- split
text1//text2- no split
text1/text2//text3 - split after text1
```

I tried using regexp.split function, but don't think it works in VBA. When it comes to pattern I was thinking something like below:

```
(?i)(?:(?<!\/)\/(?!\/))
```

but I also get error when executing search in my macro while it works on sites like: https://www.myregextester.com/index.php#sourcetab

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a RegExp match approach rather than split one. You need to match any character other than `/` or double `//` to grab the values you need.

Here is  a "wrapped" (i.e. with alternation) version of the regex:

```
(?:[^/]|//)+
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU6vQ7/2)

And here is a more efficient, but less readable:

```
[^/]+(?://[^/]*)*
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU6vQ7/3)

Here is a working VBA code:

```
Sub GetMatches(ByRef str As String, ByRef coll As collection)

Dim rExp As Object, rMatch As Object

Set rExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With rExp
    .Global = True
    .pattern = "(?:[^/]|//)+"
End With

Set rMatch = rExp.Execute(str)
If rMatch.Count > 0 Then
    For Each r_item In rMatch
        coll.Add r_item.Value
        Debug.Print r_item.Value
    Next r_item
End If
Debug.Print ""
End Sub
```

Call the sub as follows:

```
Dim matches As New collection
Set matches = New collection
GetMatches str:="text1/text2", coll:=matches
```

Here are the results for the 3 strings above:

```
1. text1/text2
 text1
 text2

2. text1/text2//text3
 text1
 text2//text3

3. text1//text2
 text1//text2
```

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant and by a test run it looks exactly what i need. Have been bashing my head for half a day. Match is a new concept for me so I will need to reverse engineer to fully understand it. Thanks a lot! this will be very useful learning experience.

Comment: If you have other issues with adapting oother regexps for VBA containing lookbehinds, look for "lookbehind workaround". Note that almost always you will need to translate part of a pattern to code. Use JavaScript compliant online regex testers. As for splitting, it can be replaced with matching in the majority of cases, and is usually much more readable.

Comment: a quick question. I now remember I used similar approach to iterate through matches before, but I got the match instead of values between them. Example: For intIndex = 1 To objMatch.Count (I got returned only slash), how come in your sample it returns text? Does it have to do "For Each" statement?

Comment: You got a slash because `objMatch` contained matches. That is what a regex is for: to match specific text patterns. When you split, you still match some (sequence of) characters that serve as a separator for a given input. `For Each` just helps iterate through the matches. Or Submatches, but you do not need them since you do not have capturing groups in the pattern I suggest.

Comment: I hope you don't mind asking, but if I wanted to use same logic, but also consider word "and" in the logic? So it would split forward slash and/or by word "and". I was thinking using negative look ahead, but can't seem to make it work `(?!\sand)[^\/]+(?:\/\/[^\/]*)*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89814/discussion-between-trm-and-stribizhev).

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub customSplit()
    Dim v As Variant

    v = Split("text1/text2//text3", "/")
    v = Replace(Join(v, ","), ",,", "//")

    Debug.Print v   '-> "text1,text2//text3"
End Sub
```

or

```
Replace(Replace("text1/text2//text3", "/", ","), ",,", "//")   '-> "text1,text2//text3"
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but I was wondering if there is regex solution available. I may need more dynamic splits in the future where replace function won't just cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Data tab, then Text to Columns option. Later, choose "Delimited" option and then select "other" and put any delimiter you want.

Comment: How do you get the Text To Columns function to only split on single slashes (`/`) and not double slashes (`//`)?

Comment: =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))))

Comment: =iferror(RIGHT(H15,LEN(H15)-SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(H15,"/","|",LEN(H15)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(H15,"/",""))))),"-")

Answer (score 0):

Text to columns will work. Another option, if you want to keep the original value, is to use formulas:
in B1

```
=left(a1,find(":",a1)-1)
```

in C1

```
=mid(a1,find(":",a1)+1,len(a1))
```