# Split string on double forward slashes and/or on specific word with RegExp

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm trying to split text by double forward slashes and/or by a specific string such as "and".

```
Example A:
text1 a/s // text2 a/b
text1 a/s and text2 a/b


Example B:
text1. // text2,// text3-
text1. and text2, and text3-
```

- Example A returns two matches: text1 a/s text2 a/b
- Example B returns three matches: text1. text2, text3-

I got very useful tip how to split by single forward slashes:
[Split string on single forward slashes with RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586057/split-string-on-single-forward-slashes-with-regexp/32588080#32588080), but trying to find a solution to exclude two forward slashes or a string, proved to be too challenging.

Bonus points if it's possible to combine one solution for both examples combined:

```
Example C:
text1 a/s // text2, and text3-
```

I would appreciate only RegExp solutions compatible with VBA.

Comment: Why not just use `v = Split(YourString, " // ")`   ?

Comment: Please specify if the spaces around `//` and `and` are included in the tokens, or if it's supposed to trim it

Comment: I was hoping to get solution that it would split with or without spaces. Split and replace is a possible solution, but it is very fixed. Must be with spaces surrounded, otherwise it might split middle of the word or two slashes out of three if someone mistypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you already have a working solution for a different split char in [Split string on single forward slashes with RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586057/split-string-on-single-forward-slashes-with-regexp/32588080#32588080). That code does not actually split the string, but it matches everything except "`/`"s. It then returns the result of each individual match in a `collection` (yes, it ends up splitting).

What you need to do here is match each character in `str`, unless the next characters are either `//` or `and`. We can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this.

Just change the pattern in your code with the following:

```vb
.Pattern = "(?!$)((?:(?!//|\band\b).)*)(?://|and|$)"
```

Alternatively, if you want to trim spaces for each token, use the following regex:

```vb
.Pattern = "(?!$)((?:(?!\s*//|\s*\band\b).)*)\s*(?://|and|$)\s*"
```

Although this will also match the `//` or `and`, it's using a [`( group )`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to capture the actual token. Therefore, you have to add the tokens to the collection using `.SubMatches(0)` (what was backreferenced by the first group).

In your code, instead of adding `coll.Add r_item.Value`, use:

```vb
coll.Add r_item.SubMatches(0)
```

---

Note: if your string has line breaks, don't forget to set the `rExp` object with `.Multiline = True`.

---

#### VBA Code:

```vb
Sub GetMatches(ByRef str As String, ByRef coll As Collection)

    Dim rExp As Object, rMatch As Object

    Set rExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With rExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "(?!$)((?:(?!\s*//|\s*\band\b).)*)\s*(?://|and|$)\s*"
    End With

    Set rMatch = rExp.Execute(str)
    If rMatch.Count > 0 Then
        For Each r_item In rMatch
            coll.Add r_item.subMatches(0)
        Next r_item
    End If
End Sub
```

And this is how you can call it with your example:

```vb
Dim text As String
text = "t/xt1.//text2,and landslide/ andy  // text3-  and  text4"

'vars to get result of RegExp
Dim matches As New Collection, token
Set matches = New Collection

'Exec the RegExp --> Populate matches
GetMatches text, matches

'Print each token in debug window
For Each token In matches
    Debug.Print "'" & token & "'"
Next token
Debug.Print "======="
```

Each token is printed in the Immediate Window.

- *This code is a modified version of the code originally posted by [@stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586057/split-string-on-single-forward-slashes-with-regexp/32588080#32588080*)*

#### Output in Immediate Window:

```
't/xt1.'
'text2,'
'landslide/ andy'
'text3-'
'text4'
=======
```

---

#### More in-depth explanation

You may wonder how this pattern works. I'll try to explain with a detailed description. And to do that, let's take only the significant parts of the pattern, using the following regex (the rest isn't really important):

```
((?:(?!//|\band\b).)*)(?://|and|$)
```

It can easily be divided in two constructs:

1. First, the subpattern `((?:(?!//|\band\b).)*)` is a [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that matches each token, backreferencing the text we want to return for each match. In [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), groups are returned with [`.SubMatches()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y27d2s18(v=vs.84).aspx). Let's brake it down:

   - The inner expression `(?!//|\band\b).` first checks to guarantee it's not followed by a *split string* ("`//`" or "`and`"). If it's not, the regex engine matches **one** character (notice the dot at the end). And that's it, it matches one character allowed as part of the token we're capturing.
   - Now, it's enclosed in `(?:(?!//|\band\b).)*` to repeat it for every char it can match, we get all the characters in the token. This construct is the closest it can get to a [while loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop).

     > While it's not followed by a split string, get next char.
   - If you think about it, it's the construct `.*` we all know, with an extra condition for each character.
2. The second subpattern `(?://|and|$)` is easier, simply match a *split string* ("`//`", "`and`" or the end of line). It's inside a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), meaning it will be matched, but it won't *store* a copy of its value.

For example:

```
text1 a/s and text2 a/b//last
^        ^| |               [1]: 1st subpattern, captured in Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
|--------|^-^
|   1      2|               [2]: Split string, not captured but included in match
|-----------|
      3                     [3]: The whole match, returned by Matches(0)


For the second match, Matches(1).Value = " text2 a/b//"
                      Matches(1).Submatches(0) = " text2 a/b"
```

The rest of the pattern are simply details:

3. `(?!$)` is to avoid matching an empty string at the end of the line.
4. All the `\s*` are there to trim the token (to avoid capturing whitespaces at the beggining or end of a token).

Comment: You are amazing! That's exactly what i needed and logic I was trying to achieve. If I understand it correctly, we only add first group that is matched? Did not know it was possible and it is very good learning experience! Even though I can't say I understand how it works even after looking at regexp references for the past week.

Comment: I tried to explore the pattern. Here are my comments, perhaps you can help me clarify how it works. http://collabedit.com/ws2wj Thanks again for all the support

Comment: New edit with "More in-depth explanation". I think it covers your comments. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Great explanation. I would up vote hundred times if i could. To clarify particular part: '(?:(?!//|\band\b).)*)' Shouldn't each character be matched but not captured in memory because of "?:". If I remove it from equation, what affect does it have? I can see changes in https://regex101.com/r/mS5pC6/1 but don't know why

Comment: `(?:group)` does not forbid a capture, think of it as a normal group. It's the other way around, a `(capturing group)` stores what has been matched. In that particular case, it allows the `*` quantifier to be applied to what's inside: `(?!//|\band\b).` is repeated 0 or more times. If you convert it to a capturing group, you will have the last character matched returned by `.SubMatches(1)` (or **2.** in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mS5pC6/1))

Answer (score 1):

Or simplest way is:

```
Text = "text1 a/s // text2, and text3-"
text = Replace(text, " // ", vbNewLine)
text = Replace(text, " and ", vbNewLine)

arr = Split(text, vbNewLine)

For Each field In arr
  WScript.Echo Trim(field) 'Using Trim you can remove the spaces around
Next
```

You will get:

```
text1 a/s
text2,
text3-
```

Comment: you would want to put a space before and after `"and"` so that it does not split a word like `landslide`

Comment: The solution is not RegExp based and will be of no practical value for OP.

Comment: I know that, I just gave this answer as an alternative.