# Match text separated by SINGLE forward slash only

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to split strings similar to this using `Regex.Split`:

- https://www.linkedin.com/in/someone

To return this:

- https://www.linkedin.com
- in
- someone

Effectively, ignoring double forward slash and only worrying about a single forward slash.

I know I should be using something like this `/(?!/)` negative look ahead - but can't get it to work.

**This is not a duplicate of this [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586057), because if you run that regular expression through Regex.Split, it does not give the required result.**

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: @Praveen, while I appreciate your answer - perhaps you should read my question again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string on single forward slashes with RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586057/split-string-on-single-forward-slashes-with-regexp)

Comment: There is a solution at the above duplicate that produces the exact desired result using the following pattern (`[^/]+(?://[^/]*)*`)...

Comment: Why not use the [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead? `Uri.Segments` will return all segments of the path. `Host` will return `www.linkedin.com`. It won't be affected by query parameters and fragments like a regex either. `new Uri(@"https://www.linkedin.com/in/someone?someparam=foo#tab1").Segments` will return `\ `, `in`, `someone`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this: `(?<!/)/(?!/)`

Breaking it down:

- `(?<!/)`: negative lookbehind for `/` characters
- `/`: match a single `/` character
- `(?!/)`: negative lookahead for `/` characters

Taken together, we match a `/` character that does not have a `/` both before and after it.

Example usage:

```
string text = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/someone";
string[] tokens = Regex.Split(text, "(?<!/)/(?!/)");
foreach (var token in tokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Token: {token}");
}
```

Output:

> Token: https://www.linkedin.com
>   Token: in
>   Token: someone

Comment: Your solution is better than mine. I have no idea why I didn't use `Regex.Split()`. +1 for simplicity.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it using this code :

```
string pattern = @"([^\/]+(\/{2,}[^\/]+)?)";
string input = @"https://www.linkedin.com/in/someone";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) {
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Output :

> ```
> https://www.linkedin.com
> in
> someone
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Panagiotis Kanavos  in the comments section above, why make things complicated when you can use the [`Uri Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx):

*Provides an object representation of a uniform resource identifier (URI) and easy access to the parts of the URI.*

```
public static void Main()
{
    Uri myUri = new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/in/someone");   
    string host =  myUri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter  + myUri.Host;
    Console.WriteLine(host);        
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

DEMO:

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GFlcNk)